# What name does this syntax have

Tags: nim-lang

In the language nim, one can do the following thing:

```
let num = 5.add(3)
```

which would be the same as

```
let num = add(5,3)
```

So, basically you take the expression before the dot as the first argument to the function.
I'm sure other languages have this feature, but none directly came to mind.

What I want to know is what name this syntax has

Comment: It looks like Object-Oriented syntax. Most languages don't let you switch back and forth like this, you have to use one or the other depending on the type of function.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it, but it isn't. This syntax can be used on any function, not just methods

Comment: I'd say it was just using a "method declared in the type definition" (quoting from the following link). If you created your own which behaved like that, it would be called an [extension method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method) in C# and VB.

Answer (score 7):

In D lang this syntax is called [Uniform Function Call Syntax (UFCS)](http://dlang.org/function#pseudo-member).

Answer (score 6):

[The manual](http://nim-lang.org/manual.html) says it's the [method call syntax](http://nim-lang.org/manual.html#procedures-method-call-syntax). It also mentions [dot operators](http://nim-lang.org/manual.html#special-operators-dot-operators).

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - *Unified [Function] Call Syntax*, or whatever you like, because there's no stable widely accepted term for that in software engineering.

The concern is based on the info about programming languages that somehow implement this feature:

1. ***C++***: The most generic name for the feature is possibly `Unified Call Syntax` as defined by [Herb Sutter at open-std.org paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4165.pdf) in cooperation with Bjarne Stroustrup as a possible new feature for further C++ standards.
2. ***D2***: In [D language](http://dlang.org/), and also in and [RFC for the Rust Language](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/132/files?short_path=a469353#diff-a469353da9b0f7d92f0e04b6815f2c52) it is called [UFCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax) (`Unified Function Call Syntax`).
3. ***MATLAB***: In [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) they [don't use any specific naming](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/calling-object-methods.html) for the fact methods can be called either via `function notation` or via `'.' (dot) syntax`.